# Javascript fetch API chain "then"

Tags: javascript, fetch, httpresponse

I'm kind of new to JS and can't figure out how to make the following work:

I'd like to run functions (for test reasons *console*) in the different stages of the fetch API. Like run console when `fetch started because of click –> then when fetch received a response (text) -> then when the fetch response has been parsed -> and finally when the parsed response text has replaced the HTML of an existing DOM-element`.

```
var doFetch = (url) => {
  fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: new Headers({
        'X-Requested-With': 'fetch'
    })
  }){
    console.log("fetch request started because of click on element");
  }
  .then(response => response.text();
    console.log("fetch request has received the response text");
  )
  .then(response => {
    let content = new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, "text/html");
    console.log("the received request response text was DOMparsed");
  })
  .then(response => {
    let main = content.querySelector('main').innerHTML;
    console.log("the parsed response content replaced current HTML");
  }
};
```

Any tips on how to correct the code would be gladly welcomed!

Comment: you should return after console then only next then will get response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

each then block will execute if previous then block return.

Your first `console.log` statement should be at the start of the `doFetch` function. It cannot be written where it is currently written in your code.

You should also chain a `catch` block at the end to catch any errors that might occur in the promise chain.

As a side note, you should use `const` or `let` keywords to declare variables instead of `var`.

```
const doFetch = (url) => {
  console.log("fetch request started because of click on element");

  fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: 'X-Requested-With': 'fetch'
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log("fetch request has received the response text");
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log("the received request response text was DOMparsed");
    return new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, "text/html");
  })
  .then(response => {
    let main = content.querySelector('main').innerHTML;
    console.log("the parsed response content replaced current HTML");
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I managed to make it work. The syntax of the headers in your correction is wrong though, I think, because I had it wrong in the first place (copy-paste). Thx again!

Comment: Apparently I can't return two values though. Maybe you have a suggestion on how this could work? (Sorry for formatting) `.then(text => {
        let content = new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, "text/html");
        let main = content.querySelector('main').innerHTML;
        let title = content.querySelector('title').innerHTML;
        
        function thehtml() {
          return { main,  title };
        }
      })
      .then(thehtml => {
        let all = thehtml();
        document.querySelector('main').innerHTML = all[0];
        document.title = all[1];
      })`

Comment: Accessing the *thehtml()* function in the last *then()* throws *a is not a function error*.

Comment: you can return more than one value using an array or an object. You can't access `thehtml` function as you are trying to, see [this](https://pastebin.com/F3tqh1BS).

Answer (score 0):

In order to do chaining you need to return from each `.then block`. Aslo your first `console.log()` post the fetch function had incorrect syntax

```
var doFetch = (url) => {

  fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: 'X-Requested-With': 'fetch'
  })
  .then(response => {
     console.log("fetch request has received the response text");
     return response.text();

  })
  .then(response => {
    let content = new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, "text/html");
    console.log("the received request response text was DOMparsed");
    return content
  })
  .then(content => {
    let main = content.querySelector('main').innerHTML;
    console.log("the parsed response content replaced current HTML");
  });
  console.log("fetch request started because of click on element"); // This will be executed first
};
```